# "Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.Initialize.ShowXdbInfo, Sitecore.Analytics" during Upgrade from Sitecore 8.1 to 9.1

Tags: experience-analytics, upgrade

I'm upgrading from Sitecore 8.1 rev3 to Sitecore 9.1.

The error is pretty straightforward, however I have already made sure that the 9.1 version of `Sitecore.Analytics.dll` - the DLL that contains `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.Initialize.ShowXdbInfo` - is both correctly referenced by my project and present in the `/bin` folder.

My hypothesis is that something in my 8.1 `config` is breaking the system and triggering a deceptive and misleading error message, but I'm not sure what I could do to narrow it down - perhaps replace my entire configuration with the 9.1 default and gradually replace it with mine until I find the culprit?

I hope it won't have to come down to this.

**Question**

Given the context, why I am still getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess Sitecore.Xdb.config file was corrupted and not the one expected in your Sitecore 9.1 instance,

Because In Sitecore 8.1 Sitecore.Xdb.config file contains the below pipeline entry,

```
<pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.Initialize.ShowXdbInfo, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
```

But when you check the Sitecore 9.1 Sitecore.Xdb.config file, the same pipeline is moved to Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration. When you execute the upgrade steps this might have taken care.

```
<pipelines>
            <initialize>
                <processor type="Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.Pipelines.Initialize.ShowXdbInfo, **Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration**" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
            </initialize>
        </pipelines>
```

So the error you report here is regarding the Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.Pipelines.Initialize.ShowXdbInfo which is moved from Sitecore.Analytics dll to Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration. But your config is not updated properly or your custom config is overwriting this somewhere [not sure].

Check the Sitecore.Xdb.config and look for any patch file which overwrites this entry [if any] that might be the root cause for the issue you reported.